# Adobe Flex XML creation and checking

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am working on a game in flex, and I am trying to create an xml file for each user if it is their first use, and then after that just access that file and edit it accordingly.

Is there anything that could do this same thing first off, basically create and edit some sort of save state? I assume that flex would have some kind of saving state type of thing, but I am not sure what to look for in that respect.

If not, does anyone know how to do this with xml files? Thanks!

WWaldo

Comment: Why would you ever use Flex for a game unless it has *massive* amounts of UI controls.  Flex is made for RIA, not games.  If you just want a game, use straight Flash(actionscript).  Second of all, you should look into [SharedObjects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html).

Comment: Because the library I am using if for flex, and so is the facebook lib, so I figured I would use flex

Comment: Any library 'made for flex' would be a UI library since everything else is Actionscript.  As for the facebook lib, last I checked, it was Actionscript as well.  ie. Not specific to Flex.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything that could do this same thing first off, basically
>   create and edit some sort of save state?

If you mean in memory; then any variable could do this.  Most likely pointed at some type of object/class.  If you mean "on disk" then any storage mechanism.  XML would work.  JSON would work.  A relational database would work.  IF you're building an AIR app; you could use the embedded SQLLite database.

> I assume that flex would have some kind of saving state type of thing,

Flex integrates with many servers.  But, the state of an application is very dependent upon that application.  There is no "automatic" way for Flex to know how to save your applications state.

> If not, does anyone know how to do this with xml files? Thanks!

Conceptually the same way you'd do it with any other approach.  Create an appropriate schema that represents the state of the application that you want to save.  The store it.  For most purposes, this would most likely encompass passing the data structure to a database and storing it for future loading.